# Error when using linguex.sty package

Tags: errors, linguex

My code follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{linguex}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,calc,arrows.meta}%
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}%

\usepackage{adjustbox}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\ex. \emph{Epistemic readings for the English modals}
\a. Mary may be tired after all that swimming, since she is not used to exercise.
\b. Mary must be tired after all that swimming, since she is not used to exercise.
\c. Mary can't be tired after all that swimming, since she is quite used to exercise.
\d. Mary will be tired after all that swimming, since she is not used to exercise.
\e. Mary might be tired after all that swimming, since she is not used to exercise.
\f. Mary should be tired after all that swimming, since she is not used to exercise.
\g. Mary could be tired after all that swimming, since she is not used to exercise.
\h. (If she had really gone to the pool), Mary would be tired now.

\end{document}
```

When I remove the `\g.` and `\h.` then the above code works fine, but I need those two lines, how can I achieve this? please suggest...

Thanks for both suggestions, it works well, now I have another issue:

My code as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{linguex}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,calc,arrows.meta}%
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}%

\usepackage{adjustbox}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\exg.
Blixa fub-ax. \\
the.house dissolve.green-{\scshape past} \\
`The house dissolved into a green slimy puddle.'

\end{document}
```

Output comes fine, but the baseline space, i.e., leading space is not come correctly for both places, one place it came as 12pt and in another place it came as 11pt, but it should be as 12pt, please refer the below image for clarification.

[image]

Can you suggest me that how to fix the same...

Comment: Please don't edit your question to ask a new question. Your second question has nothing to do with the first (for which you have a good answer.)  Please ask a new question (with a minimal example to show what the issue is.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual:

> The linguex macro defines three basic commands: \ex.,\a., and \b..  The first two  generate  list  environments. The  third  functions  basically  like an \item.

This means that the first entry of a  list is set with `\a.` while every subsequent entry is set using `\b.`.

Linguex additionally provides the commands `\c.`, `\d.`, `\e.`, and `\f.` to achieve a WYSIWYG-effect. They do the same as `\b.`. There are no commands defined for the letters following f, which is why you get an 'undefined control sequence' error.

The following MWE therefore poduces what you want to achieve.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{linguex}%

\begin{document}
\ex. \emph{Epistemic readings for the English modals}
\a. Mary may be tired after all that swimming, since she is not used to exercise.
\b. Mary must be tired after all that swimming, since she is not used to exercise.
\b. Mary can't be tired after all that swimming, since she is quite used to exercise.
\b. Mary will be tired after all that swimming, since she is not used to exercise.
\b. Mary might be tired after all that swimming, since she is not used to exercise.
\b. Mary should be tired after all that swimming, since she is not used to exercise.
\b. Mary could be tired after all that swimming, since she is not used to exercise.
\b. (If she had really gone to the pool), Mary would be tired now.

\end{document}
```

[image]